# Claim is null when called from class implementing IHttpModule, but not null when accessed from controller

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity

I have an API application in which I have this code:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myClaim = (string)new ClaimProvider().GetClaim(Thread.CurrentPrincipal, CustomClaimTypes.Culture);            
    }
}
```

And then in a controller:

```
public MyViewModel Get(int id)
{
    return GetById(id, new ClaimProvider().GetClaim(Thread.CurrentPrincipal, CustomClaimTypes.Culture));
}
```

As you can see, in both places I call the method `GetClaim()` with the same parameters. In controller, it gives me a result. In the `context_BeginRequest` event, it returns `null`. Why does this happen? I need it not to be `null` in `context_BeginRequest`, because I want to set the current culture in one place and then use it in all the controllers.

Comment: The first one is accessing the principal too early in the request pipeline. At that point it has not been set as yet by the framework. `IHttpModule` is a very low level part of the framework while the controller  is higher up the stack and rests on top of the Asp.Net framework.

Comment: @Nkosi I assumed so. What do you suggest instead? I need to do it in one place and use it in every method of the controllers.